# VB get numbers form a text field/string

Tags: vb.net, string, numbers, line

I would like to extract the numbers in a line like this

> [Helpdesk- TestUser - 10406]  case # 10405 is registred.

lets say i would like to extract 10406 from that line, could you define that the numbers before "]" is the target? or after the "#" and how would i proceed?

Comment: does the number will stay with in `-` and `]`(example `- 10407]`) ??

Comment: the number stays in [ example - "10407"] and after case " # "

Comment: `after case " # ` after or before ??

Comment: In your question you've stated that you need to extract `10406` which is before `#`,right ?

Comment: thats right, but its an example. if you could extract before the symbol ] i could do the same after #.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly then the following solution could be used to find out number.

first import following library

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
```

and

```
  Dim mytext As String = "[Helpdesk- TestUser - 10406] case # 10405 is registred."
  Dim arr As String() = mytext.Split("]")

  Dim FirstNumber = Regex.Replace(arr(0), "\D", "") 
  ' this will fetch first number i.e 10406

  Dim SecondNumber = Regex.Replace(arr(1), "\D", "") 
  ' this will fetch second number i.e 10405
```

If this is not the solution your looking for then please elaborate your question or comment

As per [OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32436337/vb-get-numbers-form-a-text-field-string/32436611?noredirect=1#comment52739515_32436611)

The following method will iterate through all the number in a given string

```
Dim mytext5 As String = "case 10405 [Helpdesk- TestUser - 10406] case # 10405 is registred."
        Dim arr1 As String() = mytext5.Split(" ")
        For Each itm As String In arr1
            Dim num As Object
            num = Regex.Replace(itm, "[^0-9]", "")
            If IsNumeric(num) Then
                'Your Code
            End If
        Next
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: one more thing, what if i want to add some text like " Here is the number " + " the number" infront of "[" ?

Comment: okey, ive got the number but now i want to add the number infront of  "["  Like this  " case 10405 [Helpdesk- TestUser - 10406] case # 10405 is registred."

Comment: @Itszani this(http://hastebin.com/ihuqevecuk.vbs) will iterate through all the numbers in a given string

Answer (score 1):

you could try something like this .....

```
scanStr = "[Helpdesk- TestUser - 10406] case # 10405 is registred"

StartPos = Instr(scanStr, "#")
EndPos = Instr(scanStr, " in")

strSubstr = Mid$(scanStr, StartPos , (EndPos - StartPos) )
```